# Duplicate key error after adding data in a table with seeded entities

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net5

The situation is the following: I am using .NET 5 and Entity Framework. I have a seeder, which looks like that:

```
    public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Entity[] entities = new Entity[]
        {
            new Entity
            {
                Id = 1,
                Description = "Test description 1"
            },
            new Entity
            {
                Id = 1,
                Description = "Test description 1"
            } 
        }
    }
```

My entity is the following, nothing special:

```
public class Entity 
{
    [Key]
    public ins Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    public IList<AnotherEntity> AnotherEntity { get; set; } = new List<AnotherEntity>();
}
```

I want to add another entity to the database (I am using MySQL) not from the database directly, but using EF, but when I try to do it (call .SaveChanges()), I get an error saying that there is a duplication in PK, because EF does not understand that there is already data in this table.

What is the best way I can handle the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your table definition and the relevant part of the model builder for configuring `Entity` please? I think this might help narrow down the issue

Comment: @YoannaKostova add Microsoft Identity to your PK field, either in the entity model (code first) or in SQL Mgmt Studio (db first)

Comment: @GarethD the entity is very simple, the issue does not come from the relations of this property but more from the fact that EF does not catch the fact that there is already seeded data and starts counting from 1, from there the issue occurs. This is the error I get: MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry '2' for key 'entitity.PRIMARY'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I discovered is that if in the OnModelCreating method you add:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(b => b.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
```

The database manages to understand that there is already seeded data and generates not duplicate Ids.